# Grails command not starting

Tags: java, grails

When I run `grails` on command line I get

```
Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

- I have `JAVA_HOME` set as `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home`
- `java -version` returns:
  `java version "1.7.0_75" 
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)`
- *grails* version is `2.4.3`

I'm stuck at this point. The error message does not help at all. How to fix this issue?

Comment: more infos with `--stacktrace --verbose --debug`?  is your `GRAILS_HOME` set?

Comment: Yes, `GRAILS_HOME` is set correctly. And `--stacktrace --verbose --debug` flags don't produce any other info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by running

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions 
rm CurrentJDK 
ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents CurrentJDK
```

in terminal.

Comment: I am using windows, I m also struck with same error, what should i do for this?.

Comment: Install and use java version 1.7.0.51.